# OutOfMemoryException when loading a big file

Tags: c#, json, out-of-memory

I would like to get some help on an Exception I'm receiving.
I'm compiling in C# 4.7.2
I've got a potentially big file that I need to load in order to call a webservice with the file content. But loading this file eventually throws an OutOfMemoryException.

I can't change the webservice I'm calling.

I would like to keep using the JsonWriter as this is the only way I found avoiding another OutOfMemoryException when writing the json into my request.

My code :

```
// loading my file content
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(path); // OutOfMemoryException throws here.

// Creating a httpWebRequest to post my file's content in a webservice
// myHttpWebRequest is of HttpWebRequest type

// I'm using the StreamWriter and JsonWriter in order to avoid throwing an OutOfMemoryException in the Json serialization when using a personalized object or a JObject with the ToString() method.
using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(), new UTF8Encoding()))
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(requestWriter))
{
    writer.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("fileContent");
    writer.WriteValue(fileContent);
    // writing other properties and values in here
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}

// after this code there is no need of my file content anymore
```

By looking at different topics, I guess I need to do a File.ReadAllLines in order not to load the entire content in memory. The problem here is that I don't know how I can write it into the JsonWriter without loading the full string ?

I guess a way would be to get rid of JsonWriter, use a StringWriter and create the Json manually, but I wish I could avoid that because of code readibility.

Comment: how big is the file?

Comment: IMO, getting an `OutOfMemoryException` when using a JSON file means that JSON is not the appropriate format to handle your datas

Comment: Not really big. Should not go over 40Mo. We have up to 10 threads running at the same moment and other applications on the server.
The file does not contains JSON. The webservice uses json as posted datas (including the file's content) and sadly I can't change this webservice